# Visual Studio Refuses to pause after debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Up until now, I have never had a problem with visual studio terminating the program after running. I have been using it for almost two years in c++. I have visual studio 2019. Now, I have to manually write  `system("pause");`
at the bottom of `main` . It's not that its too much of a hassle, but I am curious if anyone knows why it would mysteriously stop automatically pausing?

Comment: See if *Tools / Options / Debugging / General / Automatically close the console when debugging stops* got checked somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the automatically close the console when debugging stops is unchecked.
Tools > Options > Debugging > General > automatically close the console when debugging stops